# Eigenfunctions for $1s$ hydrogen Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, atomic-physics, hydrogen

I am a computer scientist and started my Phd in material science. The second course os my Phd is material simulation by computer. One the task is show the verification of the eigenfunction $1s$ from time-independent Schrodinger equation.

I dont want any answer, I just need a few tips.

I already found one example in Eisberg book (*Quantum Physics of Atoms, Molecules, Solids, Nuclei, and Particles,* pg ~ 242 Example 7-2).

In the Eisberg book I can't find the points where the $\Psi_{2 1 1}$ have influence in the demonstration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time-independent Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom is

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\vec \nabla^2\psi-\frac{e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0r}\psi=E\psi $$

If your aim is just to *verify* that the $1s$-wave function

$$\psi_{100}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi a^3}}e^{-r/a}\hspace{2cm} a\equiv \frac{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}{me^2} $$

is indeed an eigenfunction, then your task isn't all that hard. Simply plug take the necessary derivatives, add the second term, and check that the outcome is indeed of the form $C\psi_{100}$ where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: $$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\vec \nabla^2\psi-\frac{e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0r}\psi=E \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi a^3}}e^{-r/a} $$ something like that ? (change the other $\Psi$ too)

Comment: Yes, just put the right expression everywhere where there used to be a $\psi$, and you'll end up finding out if it's an eigenfunction.